# Eclipse refresh

Tags: java, eclipse, refresh

In Eclipse, when I refresh the project, most of the times it refreshes 98% of the project with regular speed and then the progress of refreshing stucks at 98%.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Attach with jvisualvm in the JDK and profile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you have big files near the end. Normally refresh goes very fast if nothing has changed because it uses only the file modified time, but if many files have been modified, or if they are very large then it can take lots more time.

A simpler way to check than profiling would just be to get a few thread dumps of your Eclipse while it's happening, then you can easily see what's going on. If you don't understand then, then attach them to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said, I may be having large files at the end. Agreed. But, then as you have mentioned, Eclipse uses only the file modified at that time. Then, it is less likely that the same big file is changed every time. So, why this might be happening almost every time I refresh?